# vuex dynamic module register shows object empty

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have registered vuex module with this function `this.$store.registerModule(this.name, 'some_module')` module created but showing empty in vuedevtools.

and I'm trying to dispatch with this code `this.$store.dispatch(this.name+'/some_action', this.id)`this return error unknown action type

please help anyone how to create vuex module dynamically.

store index.js

```
    import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

// Load store modules dynamically.
const requireContext = require.context('./modules', false, /.*\.js$/)

const modules = requireContext.keys()
  .map(file =>
    [file.replace(/(^.\/)|(\.js$)/g, ''), requireContext(file)]
  )
  .reduce((modules, [name, module]) => {
    if (module.namespaced === undefined) {
      module.namespaced = true
    }

    return { ...modules, [name]: module }
  }, {})

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules
})
```

somo_module.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import * as types from '../mutation-types'

// state
export const state = {
    count: ''
  }

  // getters
  export const getters = {
    count: state => state.count
  }

  // mutations
  export const mutations = {
    [types.GET_COUNT] (state, data ) {
      state.count = data
    }
  }

  // actions
  export const actions = {

    async some_action ({ commit }, payload) {
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.post('/count/'+payload)
        commit(types.GET_COUNT, data )
        // console.log(data)
      } catch (e) {

      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include more code? Are you declare module with `namespaced`?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to make sure that **this.name !== undefined** then you can dynamically add the module to the store like this (according to the [DOC](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#dynamic-module-registration) and [API Reference](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#registermodule))

```
this.$store.registerModule(this.name, {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    some_items: []
  },
  getters: {
    items: state => state.some_items
  },
  actions: {
    someAction () {}
  },
  mutations: {}
})
```

And use it as you always do `this.$store.dispatch('yourModule/someAction')`

If you wish you can also update your *store index.js* like this in order to register modules that have been exported by default as object

myModule.js

```
const state = {}
const actions = {}
const getters = {}
const mutations = {}

const module = {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  getters,
  mutations,
  actions
}

export default module
```

---

store index.js

<sub><sup>As you can see below i only made a small changes to the *reduce* method</sup></sub>

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

// Load store modules dynamically.

const requireContext = require.context('./modules', false, /.*\.js$/)

const modules = requireContext.keys()
  .map(file =>
    [file.replace(/(^.\/)|(\.js$)/g, ''), requireContext(file)]
  )
  .reduce((modules, [name, mod]) => {

    let module = mod.default || mod

    if (module.namespaced === undefined) {
      module.namespaced = true
    }

    return { ...modules, [name]: module }
  }, {})

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules
})
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining how it works / how it answers the question.